# Maven does not download dependencies which it requires for an external project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, dependencies

Say I have a project A that has some dependencies which it requires to function. Then I use this A in a B project. B only depends on A and transitively depends on every A dependency, but that is not mentioned in B's pom. B's only defined dependency in pom is A.

A is packaged in a jar without the dependencies, so that it is leightweight.

B project works well on my pc. I have all the dependencies in my local repository. B project only has A in pom.

There is another computer which is absolutely clean, has NetBeans and has A's jar and B project. B does not run well. It requires all A dependencies defined in it's pom. The whole dependency tree. If dependencies are not defined, it throws NoClassDefFoundException most of the time. It requires all transitive dependencies defined in A's pom to run. On my pc, only A is required to be defined in B and transitive dependencies are downloaded, if they are missing in local repository.

What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the previous answers, ProjectB builds fine on your machine as ProjectA and the associated metadata is available in your local repository.

**Why it's failing on your second PC?**

Maven identifies dependencies and transitive dependencies from the pom files. When you define projecta as a dependency in projectb, it will look for it in the local/remote repositories. It will also look for projecta's pom file and figure out any transitive dependencies and the cycle goes on. In your case you don't have projecta's jar file /pom file or associated metadata in the local repository of the second computer.You also haven't defined any remote repository from where Maven can download the projecta's pom/jar and associated meta data.So there is no way by which Maven can download/copy projecta's pom/jar and identify what the transitive dependencies are

Below are few solution which will help you resolve this problem. Let's call your 'another computer' as PC_B

Solution 1. Build ProjectA on your 'another' computer and then build ProjectB

Solution 2. If you can't build ProjectA on PC_B, then you have to make it available in your local/remote repository

a. Make it available in the local maven repository of PC_B using this command

```
  mvn install:install-file -Dfile=projecta-1.0.jar -DpomFile=projecta-pom.xml
```

(you will have to copy the jar and ProjectA's pom file over to PC_B)

Once you do this, ProjectA and the associated metadata will be added to the local maven repository on PC_B and hence you should be able to build ProjectB

**OR**

b. Create a common artifact repository to store your artifacts.There are many opensource repository managers like [archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi), [nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) etc which can help you with this.You can then configure this repository as one of the remote repositories in your maven pom/settings files.
You can use `mvn deploy` to deploy artifacts to this remote repository(after doing the necessary configuration). So you can deploy ProjectA to the remote repository, so that when ProjectB is built on PC_B, it can get the required artifacts from the newly configured remote repository.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out ASAP and will let you know about the results. The solution I am going to try is Solution 2 - I cannot give the other computer source files, thus he cannot build the project. But I can give him Jar and pom. He did install jar in his local repository, but did not use -DpomFile I think. This is what might have been missing in his local repo for the B build to function properly (to get from A pom transitive dependency information).

We do use nexus, but it seems like we should not let the user gain access with his computer to this repository.

Comment: I tried it out, it seems like it is working. I simulated it with different projects, but it seems like missing POM in local repo causes the dependency not to be known and downloaded thus failing. When I added the POM it worked. I thought it would reach for the POM into the jar, but this seems not the way maven does it. I asked the owner of the other pc to try this out with this pom. If the problem will persist I will add information, but I really feel like this is probably the solution - I will mark it after confirmation. Thanks again.

Comment: If he did an `mvn install:install-file` without providing a pom file, maven will automatically generate a pom file (without any dependency information) and install it to the local repo. This will obviously lead to ClassNotFound type of exceptions if ProjectA has got some dependencies. You are right in assuming that Maven doesn't look into the pom within the jar. You can even remove the pom from the packaging by providing  `<archive><addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor></archive>` in the maven-jar-plugin's configuration.

Comment: I am pretty sure he did it as you mention here in your comment. Thank you very much for the clarification! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Project A is deployed to your local repository, so it works locally when you use project A inside project B. After you developed project A you released the project to your local repo. To fix this problem you can e.g. deploy the project A to some repositories available on-line and then use this repository or you can pack project A to jar file with all the dependencies and include in the project B pom file.

Comment: So what you are saying is that if A has dependencies defined, which are on a central repository, but it does not pack it inside its jar and when you give this jar to someone, it will not work? Even though it is a maven project? It will only work if you package all the dependencies into the jar? When you package a maven project in a jar without dependency jars, but only with the pom that defines these dependencies and some other project depends on it, than maven will not download these missing dependencies?

Comment: Could you attach your pom files? The problem is that project A is not visible in the central repository, so you can't run project B on every computer.

Comment: Hi. Project A is probably visible in local repo for both computers. But it seems like the other computer might have installed it without the pom into the repository, which could be the problem. I will try this out. If it won't work I will attach the poms.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC has all A's dependencies, so they are not downloaded from some Maven (central) repository.

On the other computer, A's dependencies are not satisfied. Are you able to build A & B on this computer as well as on yours? Probably not.
Or do you just want to **run** B on this computer? How is it packaged?
Does the NetBeans on the other computer know how to connect to the Maven (central) repository? Do you use any?

Comment: On the not working computer A is not a project but just a jar, so I cannot build it there. I just want to run B on this computer. B is a maven project. NetBeans knows how to connect to central repository on the other computer, because when he adds the dependencies to the pom, they are doewnloaded from the repository.